# WP7 XML insert into GPX

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, gpx

In my Isolated storage I have a file called Route.gpx which is getting created with this code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Route.gpx", FileMode.Create, myStore))
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1";
    XNamespace xsiNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no"),
        new XElement(ns + "gpx",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsiNs),
            new XAttribute(xsiNs + "schemaLocation",
                "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"),
            new XAttribute("creator", "XML tester"),
            new XAttribute("version", "1.1"),
            new XElement(ns + "trk",
                new XElement(ns + "trkseg",
                    new XElement(ns + "trkpt",
                        new XAttribute("lat", "7.0"),
                        new XAttribute("lon", "19.0"),
                        new XElement(ns + "time", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        )))));
    xDoc.Save(myStream);
```

But now I want to add an extra `trkpt` element, I've tried with this code:

```
XDocument doc1;
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Route.gpx", FileMode.Open, myStore))
{
    doc1 = XDocument.Load(myStream);
}

var root = doc1.Element("trkseg");
var rows = root.Descendants("trkpt");
var lastRow = rows.Last();
lastRow.AddAfterSelf(
//XElement trkseg =
      new XElement("trkpt",
          new XElement("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Route.gpx", FileMode.Create, myStore))
{
    doc1.Save(myStream);
}
```

which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957066/add-an-element-to-an-xml-file-in-isolatedstorage)
The code just catch an exception then pressed.

Comment: NullReferenceException in var rows = root.Descendants("trkpt");,   A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DistribueretTeknologi12_GPSPhonePano.dll

Comment: I think its because it cant find trkseg but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the "trkseg" element as a descendent of the root object while you're creating it at a level lower.

Try:

```
var root = doc1.Element("trk").Element("trkseg");
```

Comment: Still catch an exception (NullReferenceException was unhandled), in the new line.
I tried with this also: 
var root = doc1.Element("gpx").Element("trk").Element("trkseg"); 
Because i have an element called gpx with the namespace, but i still catch an exception.

Comment: I tried deleting the element GPX and then used your code, now it works.
But i need the GPX element.

Comment: You'll need to include the namespace qualification when you try and get the "gpx" element.